# SwiftUI 2.0 ToolbarItem Labels showing sideways

Tags: swiftui, toolbaritems

Trying to figure out how to put the icons of the new SwiftUI toolbar on top of the text, like they are supposed to be on the bottom toolbar. Currently, they show up sideways, which is weird.

[image: File and Print shown with horizontal alignment]

This is my piece of code that shows them

```
content.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
        Button {
            menu.value = .file
        } label: {
            Label(LocalizedStringKey("menu.file"),
                  systemImage: Symbol.SymbolEnum.sf_folder.systemName! )
        }
    }
    ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
        Button {
            menu.value = .export
        } label: {
            Label(LocalizedStringKey("menu.export"),
                  systemImage: Symbol.SymbolEnum.sf_square_and_arrow_up.systemName! )
        }
    }
}
```

I know it is simple to do a VStack, but I seriously thought this was the entire goal of a Label, to be able to provide something contextually adequate, and in this case, it would be a vertical orientation for the icon and text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is `LabelStyle` for this purpose, so we could configure labels as needed.

So here is possible approach

```
struct VerticalLabelStyle: LabelStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            configuration.title
            configuration.icon
        }
    }
}
```

and now apply it to entire toolbar or to needed labels only

```
Label(LocalizedStringKey("menu.file"),
      systemImage: Symbol.SymbolEnum.sf_folder.systemName! )
  .labelStyle(VerticalLabelStyle())
```

Comment: So far, seems legit. I am taken aback why this is not already automatically like that.

Comment: I ended up doing this:
     struct VerticalLabelStyle: LabelStyle {
        func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
            VStack {
                VStack {
                    configuration.icon.font(.headline)
                }.frame(minHeight: 30)
                configuration.title.font(.subheadline)
            }.padding([.leading, .trailing], 5)
            .padding(Edge.Set.bottom, 2)
        }
    }

Comment: This solution is the way to go since the Toolbar modifier has its own default label styles, by using this method we'll be able to override the default label style.